# How can I change theme in VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, themes

I searched how to change visual studio 2012 theme many time. But couldn't change it. I download themes. I do everything what guides say in import export settings. It says "Your settings were successfully imported from wekeroad-ink.vssettings." but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Tools>options>ENviorment>General There is visual experience section and you can chose Light or dark themes if you want more you can use [Visual Studio 2012 colour theme editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05)
it have few pre-made themes (especially a blue theme really great to eye) you can also tweak every colour of Visual Studio by using it.

Comment: But I want to install son_of_obsidian

Comment: I tried it it worked easily you should click import and export settings click import then click overwrite next click browse find the file you downloaded and then next again and finish your theme should now work